# How can I see the array detail in Smarty code?

Tags: php, smarty

How can I show the Array detail in the Smarty template?

in the template, I write this:

```
{$dedicatedIps}
```

then in the browser it shows `Array`.

but I want to see the Array details. How can I do that? if is pure PHP code I can `var_dump` it.

Comment: for example you can use this {$dedicatedIps|@var_dump}

Comment: @Sfili_81 Thanks, this works.

Comment: https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifiers.tpl "_Also, all php-functions can be used as modifiers implicitly (more below) and modifiers can be combined._"